Creating a table type object in PostgreSQL and use it as a PostgreSQL function parameter
I need to convert a SQL Server database to PostgreSQL and there is a table type and a procedure used that type as a input parameter how can I do this in PostgreSQL database.
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[TT_IMG_OWD_OUTWARDCLEARING] AS TABLE(
    [ITEM_COUNT] [int] NULL,
    [PROCESS_DATE] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [CLEARING_DATE] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [VALUE_DATE] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [CLEARING_CYCLE] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER] [varchar](25) NOT NULL
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PROCESS_DATE] ASC,
    [CLEARING_CYCLE] ASC,
    [BATCH_NO] ASC,
    [UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF)
)
GO

-----procedure___

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_IMAGO_OWD_OUTWARDCLEARING] 
(
    @INSERTCOLLECTION    AS TT_IMG_OWD_OUTWARDCLEARING READONLY, 
    @UPDATECOLLECTION    AS TT_IMG_OWD_OUTWARDCLEARING READONLY, 
    @DELETECOLLECTION    AS TT_IMG_OWD_OUTWARDCLEARING READONLY, 
    @INSERTCOLLECTIONIMG AS TT_IMG_OWD_OUTWARDIMAGES   READONLY,
    @UPDATECOLLECTIONIMG AS TT_IMG_OWD_OUTWARDIMAGES   READONLY,
    @PRAM_PROCESS_DATE   VARCHAR(10),
    @PRAM_BATCH_NO       VARCHAR(14),
    @PRAM_LAST_ITEM_SEQ  INT,
    @STATUS              INT OUTPUT, 
    @ERR_MSG         VARCHAR(500) OUTPUT
) 
AS 
BEGIN 

I tried creating a data type and I found out the issue so I want to find if there is another way to do this process in PostgreSQL.

You only need to tag the RDBMS you want your solution in since your already have the SQL Server solution.

Also instead of asking how to convert X to Y explain the requirements and where you are stuck. Maybe you don't need a table type at all.

This is a already existing application's database. It only need to convert to PostgreSQL. the application code created to give parameters as type. That's why I want to find is there a way to do the same process.

What is PostgreSQL doesn't have anything similar? You'll need to understand what its doing and what your alternatives might be. There are a lot of things that don't happily convert from one RDBMS to another.

is your type a temp table

How does your application call this procedure?

" It only need to convert to PostgreSQL.' - wrong. Different databases often provide/perform similar functionality very differently. Please see Migrate Your Mindset

You don't need to - any table (or view definition) you create will already be a "type" from the point of view you can use it as an arg to a function. e.g.
userdb=> create table foo(x integer, y integer);
CREATE TABLE
userdb=> create function foo_sum(myFoo foo) returns integer language sql as $$ select myFoo.x + myFoo.y; $$;
CREATE FUNCTION
userdb=> insert into foo values (3,5), (5,6);
INSERT 0 2
userdb=> select x, y, foo_sum(f) from foo f;
 x | y | foo_sum 
---+---+---------
 3 | 5 |       8
 5 | 6 |      11
(2 rows)

userdb=>

